# Sub query value in Postgresql query

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have the following query that returns the county for specific GPS coordinates

```
select namelsad from geocoder.tiger_data.county_all  where ST_Contains(the_geom, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-121.74334 38.5441)',4269))
```

The following query returns "POINT(-121.74334 38.5441)" as used in the query above.

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_SnapToGrid(g.geomout,0.00001)) As wktlonlat FROM geocode('424 3rd St, Davis, CA 95616',1) As g;
```

I'm trying to construct this into a sub query so the only thing I can define is the address. I have tried the following query, but getting a syntax error.

Below is the query I have tried

```
select 
  namelsad 
from 
  geocoder.tiger_data.county_all 
where 
  ST_Contains(
    the_geom, 
    ST_GeomFromText(
      SELECT 
        ST_AsText(
          ST_SnapToGrid(g.geomout, 0.00001)
        ) As wktlonlat 
      FROM 
        geocode(
          '424 3rd St, Davis, CA 95616', 1
        ), 
        4269
    )
  )
```

What is the proper way of combining the two queries into one so address is the only thing I would have to define?

Answer (score 0):

Sub queries need to be enclosed in parenthesis. And I think you don't need the detour to convert the point to text just to convert it to a point again.

```
SELECT namelsad 
       FROM geocoder.tiger_data.county_all 
       WHERE st_contains(the_geom, 
                         (SELECT st_snaptogrid(geomout,
                                               0.00001)
                                 FROM geocode('424 3rd St, Davis, CA 95616',
                                              1)),
                         7269);
```